# Call to a member function token() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I'm doing authorization using laravel:sanctum for the API. But, when calling the logout() method, I get the following error: Call to a member function tokens() on null. Please help me get rid of this error

AuthController

```
 public function auth(UserLoginRequest $request){

        $user = User::query()->where('login', $request->get('login'))->first();
        if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->get('password'), $user->password)) {
            return response()->json(['message'=>'Попытка входа не удалась'], 400);
        }

        $token = $user->createToken('api_token')->plainTextToken;
        $user->api_token = $token;
        $user->save();

        return response()->json(['message'=>$user->api_token], 200);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) {
        $request->user()->tokens()->delete();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Вы вышли из системы'], 200);
    }
```

api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('user', function (UserLoginRequest $request) {
    return response()->json(['login' => $request->user()->login]);
});

Route::post('auth', [AuthController::class, 'auth']);
Route::post('authStore', [AuthController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('authLogout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::get('application/{id}', [ApplicationController::class, 'showById']);
Route::get('application', [ApplicationController::class, 'show']);
Route::post('applicationStore', [ApplicationController::class, 'store']);
Route::post('applicationDelete', [ApplicationController::class, 'delete']);

Route::post('userDelete/{user}', [UserController::class, 'delete']);
Route::post('userStore', [UserController::class, 'store']);

Route::post('review', [ReviewController::class, 'show']);
Route::post('reviewCreate', [ReviewController::class, 'create']);
```

Comment: That's because `$request->user()` is null (when user logout). You need to check it before to call `->token()`.

Answer (score 5):

solved this by adding  my logout Route inside :-

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
// logout route api code here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `auth('sanctum')` instead `auth()` because of you used to sanctum auth

*It should be:*

```
auth('sanctum')->user()->tokens()->delete();
```

Comment: it is works for my case, I use currentAccessToken() for logged out current user in postman using included current bearer Token

Answer (score 2):

The code should be like following

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
    if ($request->user()) { 
        $request->user()->tokens()->delete();
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Вы вышли из системы'], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **currentAccessToken()** instead of tokens().

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me

```
auth('sanctum')->user()->tokens()->delete();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

*["We're a little bit different from other sites."](/tour)*

An answer here should be an attempt to answer the question, not a confirmation that [the other answer](/a/68905211) worked or a "Thank you." As you gain reputation, you'll earn new [privileges](/privileges) and will be able to upvote the answer or even reward the user with a bounty. These are the SO ways of saying, *"Thanks!"* You can gain reputation (and resulting privileges) by asking well-received questions, posting helpful answers, and even by making helpful edits to existing questions and answers.

Comment: A duplicate / thank-you of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66759926/4957508

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35830363)